# Discord.py send slash command from a bot to a bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am working on a bot which is supposed to send slash command in the Discord channel and those slash commands will be received by another bot in the same channel. But when I send a message formatted as a slash command, the other bot doesn't detect it as a command but as a simple text message. Here is my code;

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready.")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    async with message.channel.typing(): await asyncio.sleep(2)
    # Send a message after 5 seconds
    await message.channel.send("/spoiler 'this is spoiler'")
    return

client.run('My_Bot_Token')
```

I tried the following to get it working

1. I tried using typing() method but that didn't work.
2. I read the discord.py docs but found nothing from there that can help.
3. Searched the internet but again nothing about sending slash commands from a bot

I'd be grateful if someone could help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the bot which receives commands from another bot, you need to have control of this bot. 
You can try to rewrite the `process_commands` [function](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L1387) in discord.py since dpy automatically ignores the message (triggered by `on_message` event) sent from other bots.

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported by Discord.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of all commands that are available in the given channel. Then all you got to do is filter the one you want. The easiest way in my opinion is to go by name. Then you can call the command and give the arguments if neccessary.

```
async for cmd in channel.slash_commands():
    if cmd.name == '<sample_name>':
        await cmd.__call__(args='<sample_args>')
```

Here is a concrete example of what I am using it for with the midjourney bot:

```
import discord

TOKEN = '<your_token>'

client = discord.Client()
channel = None

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global channel

    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')

    channels = await client.fetch_private_channels()

    for c in channels:
        if 'Midjourney' in str(c):
            channel = c
            break

    if channel is not None:
        async for cmd in channel.slash_commands():
            if cmd.name == 'imagine':
                await cmd.__call__(prompt='a test image')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Hi, I was trying to do exactly the same, but your code doesn't work for me. channel.slash_commands() fails for me. I got the error:

`Error: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'slash_commands'`